# Need help with custom NBT tags (1.13)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a specific item (carrot on a stick), so that it teleports you 10 blocks in the direction facing.

Kinda new to 1.13 so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using a scoreboard "tp" to detect a carrot on a stick being used

I gave myself a carrot on a stick with a tag "Tp"

```
give @s carrot_on_a_stick{Tp:1b} 1
```

Then in a repeating command block:

```
execute as @a[scores={tp=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick"},Tp:1b}] at @s run teleport @s ^ ^ ^10
```

However when I try to use the item it does nothing.

I tried it without the tags and it worked, however I only want a specific item to trigger this.

Comment: Sethbling did something very similar once, you can download the datapack from the description: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hA0RiV3b3fU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this command instead:

```
/execute as @a[scores={tp=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick",tag:{Tp:1b}}}] at @s run teleport @s ^ ^ ^10
```

I only changed this `Tp:1b` to this `tag:{Tp:1b}`, because that is where the `Tp:1b` ends up, after you define it.

Comment: Thank you, too, your question indirectly solved a lot of my own problems (example: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/352483/232393)